# JSONArray request and SSL

Tags: android, json, parsing, ssl, https

I have a JSONArray request which is parsing from a website some info.
Recently , I encrypted it with SSL and now it's HTTPS.. how can I make it work with the SSL certificate without allowing all SSL certificates? 
Thanks!

Comment: Generally you just connect over HTTPS and the HTTP library handles everything certificate related.  Are you concerned that the connection would succeed even if the certificate is invalid?  I'm not sure what you're asking.  Also, this question really has nothing to do with `JSONArray`.

Comment: If I use the regular request only changing the http to https it doesn't parse anything... so how can I verify the website's certificate?

Comment: Https has nothing to do with parsing json. What library are you using to make the request?

Comment: I use volley to make the request

Comment: I don't use volley, but there seems to be some disagreement on what's necessary to get detailed logging.  I would get as much information in the log as possible, and you'll probably see some kind of HTTP error. https://www.google.com/search?q=volley+logging+android

Comment: Thanks, i will check it out :)